# Subspace of a vector space Definition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $W$ is a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, then:
$\dim(W) \leq \dim(V)$.
That makes me think about the definition of a subspace. For example, in $\Bbb R^3$, is $\Bbb R^3$ considered a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$? That is the only way that $\dim(W)=\dim(V)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is true.  Suppose  $U$ is a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ then $$n =\dim U = \dim V \implies U = V$$

For suppose $U$ is a proper subspace of $V$ and has equal dimension. Then there is a vector $v \in V \setminus U$. If $A = \{u_1, u_2, ..., u_n \}$ is a basis for the space $U$ then $A \cup \{v\}$ forms a linearliy independent set which has more than $n$ vectors which is impossible.